# Для чего нужен знак ~ в регулярном выражении

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Мне понадобилось обернуть все изображения в тексте в тег `div`, предварительно убрав параграфы, если они есть. Нашла аналогичный пример регулярного выражения для другого тега, изменила его под свою задачу. Всё работает, но хотелось бы разобраться как. В справке по регулярным выражениям нигде не смогла найти роль знака `~`, но если его убрать - код перестаёт работать. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что означает этот знак и как правильно используется.

```
$search = array(
    '(<p[^>]*?>(<img[^>]*?>)</p>)',
    '~(<img[^>]*?>)~'
);
$replace = array(
    '$1',
    '<div>$1</div>'
);
$result = preg_replace($search, $replace, $text);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Символы `~` обозначают начало и конец регулярного выражения. Эти символы могут быть заменены, например на `#` или `/`. Обычно выбирают символы, не используемые для описания самого регулярного выражения.

В [официальной документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) эти символы называются [разделителями](http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

Comment: 1-й и последний символы должны быть одинаковы. Не знаю, можно ли в PHP использовать парные скобки

Comment: @andy.37, [документация говорит можно](http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.delimiters.php): _Также можно использовать разделитель в виде скобок, где стартовый и завершающий разделители являются соответственно открывающей и закрывающей скобками. (), {}, [] и <> являются допустимыми парами разделителей._

Comment: `/(.*)/isu` После разделителя могут быть модификаторы. В таком случае первый и последний символ различаются.

Comment: @ilyaplot, Вы правы. Я имел в виду, что символы разделителя д.б. одинаковы или быть парными скобками: `{(.*)}isu`.

Comment: Спасибо. А подскажите ещё, почему в первом случае без этих символов всё работает? Там, где `'(<p[^>]*?>(<img[^>]*?>)</p>)'`

Comment: @АннаКуимова, andy.37 как раз этот момент затронул. В первом варианте разделителем являются скобки. Да, если Вы получили ответ на свой вопрос, отметьте его решением, пожалуйста.

Comment: @ilyaplot, но ведь во втором скобки тоже есть

Comment: @АннаКуимова Во втором варианте скобки уже не являются разделителем. Почитайте ссылки из моего ответа, особенно вторую. У Вас сразу же после прочтения перестанут возникать подобные вопросы.

Comment: то есть получается, что если убрать разделитель (в данном случае `~`), то скобки будут вместо него восприниматься как разделитель, а не подмаска, и ссылка `$1` будет пустой?

Comment: да, именно так.